# How to know from which seed node the data is coming in cassandra using Java

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, astyanax

I am using cassandra 3.2.1 And now I want to ensure that data is coming from which node using any library called datastax or astyanax in Java.

Is it possible?

Comment: It's not possible to answer your question because the question itself is not clear ...

Comment: I want to know from which node the record is coming.For example suppose 10 records i am fetching from database and i have 6 nodes with replication factor 4. i want see each record is coming from which node.

Comment: Is it clear now? or can i explain you in detail.

Comment: Don't provide clarifications in comments. Edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know from which node the record is coming.For example suppose 10 records i am fetching from database and i have 6 nodes with replication factor 4. i want see each record is coming from which node.

You can't have this information on the "row" level. All you can have is which node is sending you data for which partition

To know that, activate **query tracing**: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/tracing-in-cassandra-1-2

Comment: So, we can not get this in browser level right? instead of command level.

Comment: OpsCenter has query tracing as part of the perf services tab. DevCenter also has query tracing.

Comment: Ok Thanks, i will try with those.